# How to position useTransition sidebar to the extreme right

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I am trying to position this sidebar just the opposite of what it is currently doing. I want the sidebar to come in from the right and stay right all through. not left.

this the sandbox link for you to reproduce - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-sidebar-transition-forked-igmgr.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Position the sidebar to the right first.

```css
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

Change the transform to positive x direction

```js
from: {
  transform: "translateX(100%)"
},
enter: {
  transform: `translateX(0)`
},
leave: {
  transform: "translateY(100%)"
},
```

Comment: Adding `overflow: hidden` to `body` or some other container for your sidebar might also be a good idea to avoid scrollbars